# jquery doesnt run in php app

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine

In my php app，I have a jquery，but it doesn't run,other parts doing well,And Im sure it run well in my host .It is like this in my html:`<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`
So I guess something wrong in my app.yaml.

The following is my app.yaml:

```
application: *
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: photo/\1
  upload: photo/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))

- url: /jquery.min.js
  static_files: photo/\1
  upload: photo/jquery.min.js

- url: /index.html
  static_files: photo/\1
  upload: photo/index.html  

- url: /albums/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|swf$))
  static_files: photo/albums/\1
  upload: photo/albums/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|swf$))


- url: /(.+)
  script: photo/\1
  secure: always

- url: /photostack.php
  script: photo/photostack.php
  secure: always
```

I am a biginner,so maybe its just a small problem. But I work on it for days,still cannot find the way. Please help me .This is my website: `https://nicol06215.appspot.com/index.html`It supposed to show window when you click the column.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in your yaml is:

```
url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
```

So if you request `yoursite.com/jquery.min.js` the previous line matches that url and the request should look for jquery.min.js in photo.

The second and third handler should not be needed.

Then it looks like you do it again in

```
- url: /(.+)
```

This matches everything so the next handler (last one) is handled by this as well and isn't needed/used.

If you request `yoursite/jquery.min.js` do you get a not found error?

I think if you want index.html to be used when a user requests the root you can do the following:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: photo/index.html
```

At the moment your next and prev.png aren't uploaded but there are no script errors. You are using a pretty old version of jQuery but if it works for you then that's fine.

Comment: Thanks,and I change it as you said, there is no problem with  https://nicol06215.appspot.com/jquery.min.js   ,but I still can not fix my website. One more thing is I have to enter with /index.html ,its wield for me. https://nicol06215.appspot.com/index.html

Comment: yes,I think you are right, the key is the old version, I will try some new ones,thanks a lot.

Comment: `handlers:
- url: .*
  static_files: photo/index.html` this works for  index.html

Answer (score 0):

You've got your answer, but you may like to know how I link to jQuery and use it in my GAE app.

I made 2 folders `styles` and `scripts` and put my scripts and styles files in them. Then in my HTML "head" tag link to them just like a normal website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/list.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then in my yaml file I defined them like this:

```
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts

- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles
```

In this way I don't need to specify a handler for every single file-name request. I simply say whatever request starts with "styles" or "scripts" (eg:`- url: /scripts`), use the styles or scripts folder/directory (eg:`static_dir: scripts`) to handle it.

Comment: You can also link to a CDN like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` so you don't have to specify it in your YAML anymore.